# Could I control which protocol will ODBC uses to connect MSSQL on "integrated windows authentication"

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, kerberos

I have a Windows machine that should connect to an MSSQL instance with an ODBC driver using "windows integrated authentication".

Now according to the specifications of the [login message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/773a62b6-ee89-4c02-9e5e-344882630aac) the server is using SSPI for that. And if I understood the [sspi documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/ssp-packages-provided-by-microsoft) correctly, then SSPI could be use by Kerberos, NTLM or some other authentication protocol.

Now let's say that I want to enforce ODBC to user Kerberos, is it possible to do that by configuring either one of the following components?

- SQL Server
- Active Directory
- ODBC driver

(Hope that my question makes sense? I am really new to the world of Windows authentication and protocols and really confused by all the docs..)

Comment: As far as I know you configure it at the AD level, please read: http://woshub.com/disable-ntlm-authentication-windows/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server will always prefer Kerberos over NTLM, however, NTLM is used as a fallback by SQL Server to ensure connectivity. You cannot disable NTLM authentication at the SQL level, this can only be done at the domain level, however, if you have Kebreros authentication properly configured then SQL Server will use that over NTLM.

See this article for information on properly configuring Kerberos in SQL Server:

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/configuring-kerberos-authentication